Type a date on Android
I have a .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid and Web App.
The challenge that I have, is that when I run the solution on windows and in a browser, I am able to type the date in an InputDate field, but on Android it does not allow me to type a date, it forces me to select the date from the date selector.
The reason I want to be able to type the date, is that if a user is born in 1969, it take a lot of scrolling to get to the correct year.
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-2">
     <label class="col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
 </div>
 <div class=" col-4">
     <InputDate @bind-Value="customer.DateOfBith"></InputDate>
 </div>
 </div>     


Instead of , you can use a standard  and apply custom validation to ensure the date is correctly formatted.
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2">
    <label class="col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <InputText @bind-Value="customer.DateOfBirthString" @oninput="ValidateDate"></InputText>
    <div class="text-danger">@dateErrorMessage</div>
</div>

@code {
private string? dateErrorMessage;
public string? customer.DateOfBirthString { get; set; }

private void ValidateDate(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var inputValue = e.Value?.ToString();
    if (DateTime.TryParse(inputValue, out var parsedDate))
    {
        customer.DateOfBith = parsedDate;
        dateErrorMessage = null;
    }
    else
    {
        dateErrorMessage = "Invalid date format. Please enter a valid date.";
    }
}

}

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
